# Google Maps API - V2 key x V3 no key

Tags: api, google-maps, key

Ok, Google Maps API V2 needs a key and V3 doesn't. My question is exactly why is that? What was the key for? And why did they take it away in V3?

Comment: Not really sure if this belongs on SO. This is a bit too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My **theory** for why they required a key in V2 was so that they could guarantee that you had agreed to the terms of use. Per their lawyers. Then for V3, the Google developers decided not to have a key because it is a pain that really doesn't guarantee anything. So in the disagreement between the developers and the lawyers, the developers won. Google is one of the few companies where that could happen.

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps API V3 makes a distinction between normal users and "premium" users. You still need a key to access the premium features of Google Maps, but the basic stuff is now available to everyone without a key.

Comment: V2 already made that distinction, but nevertheless people needed the key to make the normal version work. That doesn't really answer the question of what is it for.

Answer (score 0):

Also, with V2 it was a bit of pain when you needed a separate API key if you were developing on your local machine and you wanted to test your website on `localhost`. Now there is no key required, so no more hassle with two keys.

Comment: I don't know if it was such a hassle to go to google's page, type your address and get the key. All in all it took you 3 seconds... And when you deployed your website, you'd only need another 3s to get it again.

Comment: But it was an extra step and I think it's good that they removed it.

Comment: Btw, I think tomlog's point wasn't that it was a hassle to get a key, but rather that it was a hassle for every development system to have to make substituting keys a feature so that local dev, staging, and production environments could all have their own keys automatically put in place during deployment.