# display google-map in ASP.NET website without using map key

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I have to display a google map in my website with certain specifications. However i am not even able to display the map itself.

script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAxTQuI4cSXZdKpxGMrX3fvRQUIgdt2KQbt-zRShjtqzhqRcrL_RSS0tVWaCYz7rT9XNT1ohGSL_WXBA" type="text/javascript">/script

script type="text/javascript"

i have tried using alert within the function but it seems the function is not called at all from the code behind page.i have written the function for map display in managerview.aspx page while i am calling it from the code behind page that is the managerview.aspx.cs page.i believe there is something wrong with the line i have posted.its bcoz it was displaying perfectly fine before. but not working now. :( please help

is there a way to call google-maps without using any kind of key???

Comment: Your not supplying enough information. What is the relevant asp code how do you hook the code behind page how do you inject the javascript and how do you start it?

Comment: from the code behind file i call the javascript function like this. Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "initialize('" + finaladd + "','" + name_and_add + "')", true); 
initialise is the name of the function.and finaladd and name_and_add are strings.when i write an alert within the initialise function even that alert is not called.

Comment: Google Maps API v3 does not require a key to use (for standard usage anyway). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343917/google-maps-api-v2-key-x-v3-no-key

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to use java use iframe html code and in google it self it is explain how:
1-search your place in google map 
2-click link button on the top right of the page 
3-copy the code to your page 
its done i do it my self and its work